# Spring Data JPA aggregate functions with QueryDsl predicates

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, querydsl

I have a Spring Data Jpa repository extending `PagingAndSortingRepository` and `QueryDslPredicateExecutor`.

It points to a table that contain element I want to elaborate with an aggregate function. I want to fetch each `m.field1` with `MIN m.field2`.

So here is my query in `@Query` method annotation:

```
select new x.xx.MyClass(m.field1, MIN(m.field2))
from MyClass m
group by m.field1, m.field2
```

and here my repository interface method:

```
Page<MyClass> findMyClass(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable);
```

It works, even if probably this query sucks and there's better way to do that.

But when I try to use a predicate, even with empty one I get:

```
org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 1; 
    nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. 
    Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 1
```

So is possible to get this working, or I have to go with another implementation?